# Entity Framework Structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor

I am going through this tutorial to help me better understand the EF Structure. I currently use SQL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

In this example, it shows the instructor, office, student, course, grade, and assignments

```
    public async Task OnGetAsync(int? id, int? courseID)
    {
        Instructor = new InstructorIndexData();
        Instructor.Instructors = await _context.Instructors
              .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
              .Include(i => i.CourseAssignments)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Course)
                    .ThenInclude(i => i.Department)
                .Include(i => i.CourseAssignments)
                    .ThenInclude(i => i.Course)
                        .ThenInclude(i => i.Enrollments)
                            .ThenInclude(i => i.Student)
              .AsNoTracking()
              .OrderBy(i => i.LastName)
              .ToListAsync();

        if (id != null)
        {
            InstructorID = id.Value;
            Instructor instructor = Instructor.Instructors.Where(
                i => i.ID == id.Value).Single();
            Instructor.Courses = instructor.CourseAssignments.Select(s => s.Course);
        }

        if (courseID != null)
        {
            CourseID = courseID.Value;
            Instructor.Enrollments = Instructor.Courses.Where(
                x => x.CourseID == courseID).Single().Enrollments;
        }
    }
```

To help me better understand the syntax would this SQL Statement be the equivalent?

```
SELECT        *
FROM            Instructor INNER JOIN
                         OfficeAssignment ON Instructor.ID = OfficeAssignment.InstructorID INNER JOIN
                         Department ON Instructor.ID = Department.InstructorID INNER JOIN
                         Course ON Department.DepartmentID = Course.DepartmentID INNER JOIN
                         Enrollment ON Course.CourseID = Enrollment.CourseID INNER JOIN
                         CourseAssignment ON Course.CourseID = CourseAssignment.CourseID INNER JOIN
                         Student ON Enrollment.StudentID = Student.ID
WHERE Instructor.ID = @ID AND Course.CourseID = @CourseID ORDER BY Instructor.Lastname
```

Comment: Not really, it may be along these lines but it depends on the relationships between the entities. The best way to see the equivalent SQL is to trace it for the actual SQL and check the execution plan (the generated SQL is quite heavy going at first glance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to use entities as objects rather than thinking of them as tables. Yes, they typically correlate directly to the underlying tables, but that is a means to an end. You can leverage the relationships more directly than simply treating it as another way to write SQL.

For example:

```
   Instructor.Instructors = await _context.Instructors
          .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
          .Include(i => i.CourseAssignments)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.Course)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Department)
            .Include(i => i.CourseAssignments)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Course)
                    .ThenInclude(i => i.Enrollments)
                        .ThenInclude(i => i.Student)
          .AsNoTracking()
          .OrderBy(i => i.LastName)
          .ToListAsync();
```

This will correspond roughly to an SQL statement with a bunch of inner joins and an OrderBy clause. In the realm of EF though, this would be considered bad practice. The reason is that like an SQL statement with inner joins, you are effectively doing a "SELECT *" across all of those tables. Do you really want *all* of the columns of all of the joined tables?

`AsNoTracking()` merely tells EF that for the data retrieved, you aren't going to modify it, so don't bother tracking dirty state. This is a performance tweak for read operations.

`ToListAsync()` performs the query as an awaitable operation which will free up the thread the method was called on. No magic multi-threaded execution here, just the call can hand off to SQL Server, release it's thread, then be assigned a new thread based on a continuation point after the await.

One warning sign I see with the example is the use of the null-able parameters. Can this method validly be called with:

- Neither an ID or course ID?
  and
- An ID with no course ID?
  and
- A course ID with no ID?
  and
- Both an ID and course ID?

If any of these combinations is invalid then the method should be split up or refined.

Getting back to the "SELECT *" behaviour, using EF you have a lot of power hiding behind the scenes ready to turn Linq map/reduce operations into SQL to run against the server and return you a meaningful, minimal set of data.

For example:

```
var query = _context.Instructors.AsQueryable();
if (id.HasValue)
  query = query.Where(i => i.ID == id.Value);
query = query.OrderBy(i => i.LastName);

var instructors = await query.Select(i => new InstructorIndexData 
  {
    InstructorId = i.ID,
    // ...
    Courses = i.CourseAssignments.Select(ca => new CourseData {
      CourseId = ca.Course.ID,
      CourseName = ca.Course.Name,  
      //..
    }
  }).ToListAsync()

if (courseId.HasValue)
{
  var enrollments = await query.SelectMany(i => i.Courses.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CourseID == courseID.Value).Enrollments.Select(e => new EnrollmentData 
  {
    InstructorId = i.ID,
    EnrollmentId = e.EnrollmentID,
    CourseId = e.Course.CourseID,
    //...
  }).ToListAsync();

  // From here, group the Enrollments by Instructor ID and add them to the Instructor index data.
  var groupedEnrollments = enrollments.GroupBy(e => e.InstructorId);
  foreach(instructorId in groupedEnrollments.Keys)
  {
    var instructor = instructors.Single(i => i.InstructorId == instructorId);
    instructor.Enrollments = groupedEnrollments[instructorId].ToList();
  }
}
```

Now the caveat here is that I'm basing this on memory and with a rough guess of your structure and desired output. The key points would be leveraging the `IQueryable` and issuing `Select` statements to just pull back the exact data you need to populate the objects you want to provide to a view.

I do this in 2 query executions, one to get the instructor(s), then the second to get the enrollments if requested based on the provided course ID. Personally I'd split this into two methods since I'd expect the enrollments would be optional. Also there is a difference between fetching one instructor, and all instructors. In cases where potentially large amounts of data are returned, you should look at establishing pagination with `Skip()` and `Take()` to avoid expensive queries bogging down the CPU, network, and memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it helped me a lot.